# How to create folder in document library using batch processing

Tags: document-library, folder, console-application, batch

I need to create bulk folder(~200) in document library. I have tried using console application but it required more time to create then i have decided to create using batch processing as suggested in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926347/efficient-way-to-create-a-large-number-of-sharepoint-folders).

Here is my code

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.AppendFormat("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ows:Batch Version=\"6.0.2.5608\" OnError=\"Return\">");
for (int itemIx = 0; itemIx < 100; itemIx++)
{
    query.AppendFormat("<Method ID=\"{0}\" >" +
    "<SetList>{1}</SetList>"+
    "<SetVar Name=\"FSObjType\">1</SetVar>" +
    "<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Save</SetVar>" +
    "<SetVar Name=\"BaseName\">MyFolder{0}</SetVar>" +
    "<SetVar Name=\"ID\">New</SetVar>" +
    "</Method>", itemIx,doclib.ID);
}

query.AppendFormat("</ows:Batch>");

web.ProcessBatchData(query.ToString());
```

But somehow this is not working. It doesn't create any folder or not return any error from code block.

Or suggest me any other way to create bulk folder in less time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
$Installed=Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" }
if ($Installed -eq $null) { Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" }

$FolderNames=@("One","Two","Three")

$TargetWebURL="http://<url to site>"
$TargetWeb=Get-SPWeb -Identity $TargetWebURL
$TargetLibrary="<Library Name>"
$CI=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolderCreationInformation]::new()
$SPPath=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPResourcePath]::FromUri($TargetFolder.ServerRelativePath)
$FolderNames | ForEach-Object { $Folder=$TargetFolder.SubFolders.Add($_); $Folder.Update() }
```

Caveats:

1. Local SharePoint
2. Ran as credentials that already had sufficient permissions
3. SharePoint 2019
4. PowerShell 5.1